# How to view which code is responsible for setting a class attribute upon DOM loading?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, attributes

I have the following DOM elements which effectively comprise a table cell:

```
<div class="ms-acal-item" style="position:absolute;left:250px;top:344px;width:225px;height:41px;" title="2/2019 (100%)" _index="3,0">
  <div class="ms-acal-sdiv">
    <div class="ms-acal-time">00:00 - 00:00</div>
    <div class="ms-acal-title"><a onclick="EditLink2(this,'WPQ4');return false;" href="/DispForm.aspx?ID=25">2/2019 (100%)</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I determine which code (JavaScript?) is responsible for setting a class attribute when a page is rendered for the first time?
I tried 'break on' in the Chrome Dev tools but this seems to only work for modifications after the DOM was loaded.

In this case, I'm after the ***height*** attribute of the parent `<div>` which is rendered differently for each element based on the amount of child divs it contains.

For example, if this element's source data contains a time and a link two child `<div>` will be rendered thus resulting the parent `<div>` being 41px in height.
However, it's also possible that the first child  `<div>` containing the time, e.g. ***00:00 - 00:00*** is not present in the source. When I inspect such an element I see that the height was rendered as only being 19px in height.

I'm not very well versed in the DOM and JavaScript but I would like to know how I can determine which bit of code is resonsible for defining this attributes value when the DOM is being loaded.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess I'm overcomplicating things here and it might be a basic concept but I'm still not getting it. I mean, if ***height*** were specified in HTML or CSS it would be static right? However, here, ***height*** is dynamic. Thanks!